# Best practices for complex taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a question about complex taxonomies. What are the pros and cons of tagging multiple terms? For example, tagging the lowest "child" or all of them up to the "parent."

I'm currently working on a template and would like to know the best practices.

Comment: What does "tagging multiple terms" mean?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by _tagging multiple terms_. Assigning multiple hierarchical terms to post?

Comment: I think he means if you have a taxonomy term tree and you select a child, do you also select all the ancestors?

Answer (score 1):

Tag the lowest child only. The information for this tag contains already all the data about it’s parents.